# Custom Panel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I created a class and inherited it from the class panel and added content to it, but for some reason the window does not count it for content and the height and width of the window is set to zero.
The sizes of the window are set automatically.

```
SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"
```

If you take a simple Grid then everything is fine.
Here is my class

```
public class Field : Panel
    {
        static Field()
        {

        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            Size size = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
            foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
                element.Measure(size);
            return new Size();
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
            {
                Rect bounds = new Rect(new Point(0,0), element.DesiredSize);
                element.Arrange(bounds);
            }
            return arrangeSize;
        }
        public void CreateField(Field element)
        {
            element.Children.Add(new Cell());
        }
    }
```

Help Please!

Comment: In MeasureOverride() you return new Size() - which makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support SizeToContent, your MeasureOverride method should return the final desired size of the Panel after layout. In your example this is simply the maximum width and height of its Children:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    var measuredSize = new Size();

    foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
    {
        element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

        var elementSize = element.DesiredSize;

        measuredSize.Width = Math.Max(measuredSize.Width, elementSize.Width);
        measuredSize.Height = Math.Max(measuredSize.Height, elementSize.Height);
    }

    return measuredSize;
}
```